Siebel Error: Inbound SOAP message XML parsing failed at line number 2 and column 1
I'm using SoapUI to send a SOAP request with a MTOM file attachment to an Oracle Siebel application but am getting this error:
Error: Inbound SOAP Message - XML parsing failed at line number : 2 and column number : 1.Check log for more details

Request properties have UTF-8 encoding and MTOM enabled. Siebel server logs don't show any information on the XML parsing error.
Here's my SOAP request XML:
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://siebel.com/Service/ServiceReqs" xmlns:data="http://www.siebel.com/xml/ServiceReqIO/Data">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <UsernameToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">userfoo</UsernameToken>
      <PasswordText xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">passwordbar</PasswordText>
      <SessionType xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">None</SessionType>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
        <ser:ServiceReqExecute_Input>
            <data:ListOfServicereqio>
                <data:ServiceRequest>
                    <data:SRNumber>111111111111</data:SRNumber>
                    <data:ListOfServiceRequestAttachment>
                        <data:ServiceRequestAttachment>
                            <data:Created>10/02/2024 12:00:00 PM</data:Created>
                            <data:ActivityFileExt>png</data:ActivityFileExt>
                            <data:ActivityFileName>Image</data:ActivityFileName>
                            <data:ActivityFileSize>20000</data:ActivityFileSize>
                            <data:ActivityFileBuffer>cid:123456789</data:ActivityFileBuffer>
                        </data:ServiceRequestAttachment>
                    </data:ListOfServiceRequestAttachment>
                </data:ServiceRequest>
            </data:ListOfServicereqio>
        </ser:ServiceReqExecute_Input>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>

The indent whitespace before <soapenv:Header> can be spaces or tabs but I still get the error.
Here's the SOAP response XML:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Error Code: SOAP_ERROR Error Message: Error: Inbound SOAP Message - XML parsing failed at line number : 2 and column number : 1.Check log for more details</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <siebelf:errorstack xmlns:siebelf="http://www.siebel.com/ws/fault">
               <siebelf:error>
                  <siebelf:errorsymbol/>
                  <siebelf:errormsg>Error: Inbound SOAP Message - XML parsing failed at line number : 2 and column number : 1.Check log for more details</siebelf:errormsg>
               </siebelf:error>
            </siebelf:errorstack>
         </detail>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>


Instead of sending a MTOM attachment, I tried sending an Inline attachment and the Siebel server seemed to like that better (no XML parsing error). SoapUI Attachments and Files
